# Add Openid module in drupal 4.7.x

Tags: drupal, openid

Can any one please tell me the steps to be followed or how to configure and also to add Openid module in drupal 4.7.x.

It would be great if i can get detail steps of adding & configuring it as i am very new to this. Please help me.

Ok now i am getting both Openid login form & as well as User Login form of Drupal 4.7 in the same page.

Can we show as i shown below. Please anyone help me in this...

**User Login**

Log in using OpenID: ( Labels)

Username: * ( Labels)

```
    Log In ( Button)
```

- Cancel OpenID login   ( Links)
- Create New account    ( Links)
- Request New Password  ( Links)

Is it possible to get the Log In form in the above mentioned way. If yes can anyone tell me what we need to do to get the User Login form in the above mentioned format. What all configuration or changes in code is requied to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

get it from http://drupal.org/node/109013 and install and configure as usual.

EDIT: that being said, be advised that both Drupal 4.7 and the 4.7 version of the openid module are not being maintained anymore and contain severe security issues. if you don't want your website to be taken over, upgrade to Drupal 5 or (better) 6 and use the maintained and secure openid modules of these versions. Drupal 6 even has openid in core.

Comment: Ok fine thanks for ur reply. I have done this but still it is not reflecting in drupal site. so can u please explain me in detail if its not a problem.

Comment: read my edit. i won't support an unmaintained and unsecure module.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. So if we need to implement openid then its better to use drupal 6.

Comment: You should upgrade your Drupal version regardless. There have been done a lot of progress to Drupal itself, security fixes etc, that is not applied to Drupal 4.7. Keeping your code that runs your website up to date is always very important, both as a security means and to get the extra functionality that has been added.